# Block matrix multiplication example

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let
\begin{equation}
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6
\end{pmatrix}, \qquad
B = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 3 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Block multiply out $AB$, where $A$ is partitioned (into blocks)
\begin{equation}
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & | & 3 \\
\hline
4 & 5 & | & 6
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
So we have $A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6
\end{pmatrix} = A = \begin{pmatrix}
A_1 & A_2 \\
A_3 & A_4
\end{pmatrix}$ where $A_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$, $A_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
3
\end{pmatrix}$, $A_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
4 & 5
\end{pmatrix}$ and $A_4 = \begin{pmatrix}
6
\end{pmatrix}$ and we know the final result is a $2\times 3$ matrix but my question is how do we use $B$?
Thanks.
P.S. I didn't quite know how to put a vertical line in a matrix!

Comment: I used $B_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 3 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ and $B_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ and got the right answer thanks.

Comment: Please add this as answer to your own question.